# Querying Multiple Youtube Channels

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

How do I query multiple Youtube channels? I've attempted something like this:

```
function search() {
    // Use the JavaScript client library to create a search.list() API call.
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        part: 'snippet',
        fields: 'items(id/videoId ,snippet/thumbnails, snippet/title,
                 snippet/publishedAt)',
        channelId: 'DOESNTMATTER',
        order: 'date',
        maxResults: '50'

    });

    request.execute(function(YTDataL){
        var videoIdsL= $.map(YTDataL.items, function(item){
           return item.id.videoId; 
        });
        var videoDataL = gapi.client.youtube.videos.list({
            id: videoIdsL.join(','),
            part: 'contentDetails, statistics'
        })
        videoData.execute(function(videoDataL){
                    YoutubeResponseL(videoDataL, YTDataL);    
                });

            });            
}
```

Which works perfectly when querying one channel... But every time I try to use the same mechanism with essentially two different objects (YTData, YTDataL) It keeps giving me 10001 errors when it comes to querying the "videoId"... this time I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'videoId' of undefined
```

What should I do to Query multiple channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bit more detail for future questions: The search.list method as stated above can only search ONE channel overall... To go around that:

1) use the channels.list functionality and get the `contentDetails` of every channel you're working with.

2) In the `contentDetails` there are `playlists` in which you can find the `upload` playlist 
which is essentially almost the same as the result you get from `search.list`.

3) Use the `playlistItems.list` to list the items in the `upload` playlist.

4) Essentially create functions that list the `playlistItems` of every channel... You should get separate response objects for each channel and there you go.

Comment: @gai-appelbaum : maybe I am missing something; it seems `playlistId` (of `playlistItems.list`) doesn't accept array of `uploads` (received from `channels.list`)  either. So what is it you achive by going this round trip than running querying via `search.list` API for each of the channel id ?

Answer (score 0):

You can only query one channel with [search.list method](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).
The other option would be using [channels.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) and iterate over their videos.

Comment: So how would I go about to query the videos of more than one channel? This is sooooo confusing.

Comment: Couldn't I in theory run two different search.list requests and get two separate objects? Because that's what I'm doing, and I get everything back except that it refuses to accept that a parameter that's IN the object exists... I posted this a few weeks ago trying to solve it and so far nothing:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347829/two-exact-youtube-response-objects-one-throws-uncaught-referenceerror-id-is-n

Comment: I finally figured it out... I'm a bit disappointed though that a Google employee would give such vague answer. Non the less, you did give me a lead to the answer, but didn't answer the question...