# Setting part to snippet and contentDetails using the youtube api

Tags: jquery, youtube-api

I did some [digging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860198/querying-multiple-youtube-channels) [and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137227/gdata-api-v3-youtube-can-not-retrieve-contentdetails) [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314874/related-videos-with-part-contentdetails-and-statistics-youtube-api-v3/36318868)  similar issues with the api. Im currently using the youtube-api to search for songs. I'm currently setting `part` to `snippet` which allows me to get the thumbnail and title. However with part set to snippet I cant get the length of the video or the channel who published the video image. Currently I'm trying to trying to get the video length, which I need `part` set to `contentDetails`. I tried something like this but it didn't work, what is the correct way to use them both togheter?

```
$(function(){
$("#formen").on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $("#result").html('');
        var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            order: "viewCount",
            part: "snippet, contentDetails",
            type: "video",   
            q: encodeURIComponent($("#search").val()).replace(/%20/g, "+"), 
            maxResults: 15
        });

    request.execute(function(response) { 
    console.log(response);
        var results = response.result; 
        $.each(results.items, function(index, item) { 
            $.get("item.php", function(data) {  
                $("#result").append(tplawesome(data, [{"title":item.snippet.title, "yturl":item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url, "videoid":item.id.videoId, "channelTitle":item.snippet.channelTitle}])); 
            });
    });
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [search endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) only provides the snippet.

If you need more video details, you take the video IDs from the search result and make a call to the [video endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list). There you can request the parts you need, like contentDetails.

Comment: Do you have an example of how this is normaly done?

Comment: Example: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&id=FusR1jiyRh0&key=API_KEY