# Fetching data from youtube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to have a code where on a given search query I can get details such as video title, description, number of views, number of likes, etc. I am getting an error as
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'snippet')

The code block is below

```js
// Replace with your own YouTube API key from the credentials JSON file
const API_KEY = 'YOUR_YOUTUBE_API_KEY';

function fetchYouTubeData(searchQuery) {
  const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=${encodeURIComponent(searchQuery)}&key=${API_KEY}`;

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  const videos = data.items.filter(item => item.id.kind === 'youtube#video');

  const results = [];

  videos.forEach(video => {
    const videoId = video.id.videoId;
    const videoDetails = fetchVideoDetails(videoId);
    results.push(videoDetails);
  });

  return results;
}

function fetchVideoDetails(videoId) {
  const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=${videoId}&key=${API_KEY}`;

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  const videoDetails = {
    videoId: videoId,
    title: data.items[0].snippet.title,
    views: data.items[0].statistics.viewCount,
    likes: data.items[0].statistics.likeCount,
    dislikes: data.items[0].statistics.dislikeCount,
  };

  return videoDetails;
}
```

Comment: You cant get all that data from snippet only, this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69931359/setting-part-to-snippet-and-contentdetails-using-the-youtube-api

Answer (score 0):

In function fetchVideoDetails(videoId) at:

```
const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=${videoId}&key=${API_KEY}`;
```

You only mention the part "statistic" and "id," but then calling for "snippet" at title:

```
data.items[0].snippet.title
```

You need to mention "snippet" also.